# Java/Scala library for user login and authentication

Tags: java, scala, authentication, user-management

I want to make an app where users can authenticate, register etc. I plan to use email as the username.

Are there any libraries in Java/Scala that let me do this? The app is pretty simple so all I need is some support for the following:

1. register
2. login
3. forgot password
4. email verification link
5. security hassles (sql injection, robot protection, etc)

I will be sending emails via gmail POP, and I am open to using any database. Please point me to the correct library if any.

People have suggested using Spring security or Lift but they seem too heavyweight for my app.

Answer (score 3):

I think Secure Social could be useful for you: http://securesocial.ws/

It provides:

- Registration
- Authentication with major third party apps (twitter, facebook...)
- Secure your action
- Authorization
- Forgot password
- Welcome email
- Password encryption
- ...

And you can provide / customize your own views / emails.

EDIT : Oops, SecureSocial is reserved for Playframework only, so it will not be ok for you :(

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest and the fastest way of doing it would be using `Play`.
Crash course:

In routes, declare as

> POST         /login           controller.Dashboard.regis

And then

```
 object Dashboard extends Controller{

  val loginForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "name" -> text,
      "email" -> text,
      "pass" -> text))

  def regis = Action { implicit request =>
    val form = loginForm.bindFromRequest

    form.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest("bad reqeust "+formWithErrors),
      user => {
        val input = CreateUser(user._1, user._2, user._3)
        Try(Users.addUser(input)) match {
          case Failure(err) => InternalServerError(err.getMessage())
          case Success(x) => //so on
          }
```

I have not used but they say even Scalantra is pretty fast to catch up. But play should be pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Lift has [`ProtoUser` and `MegaProtoUser`](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-8.html#sub%3aProtoUser-and-MegaProtoUser) which makes it easy to add simple user account management to your applications.